# Easy C: Program stuck after asking for prompt

Tags: c

In the following simple program after the user inputs an integer the command line remains a flashing prompt. When I exit the program the answer is then printed out. Why is this and how can I fix it?

```
//powers of 2

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int a,b=1,i;
    printf("What power of 2?\n");
    scanf("%i\n",&a);
    for (i=0; i<a;i++)
    {
        b=b*2;
    }
    printf("the answer is: %i\n",b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Run in a debugger or add some printfs to see where it jams up. You'll learn much more from doing it that way!

Answer (score 1):

Try remove the \n in your scan :

```
 scanf("%i",&a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `\n` from `scanf`. After that I compiled your program and it worked properly.